# what is the difference with these query classes in TYPO3?

Tags: sql, class, typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm using extbase in my extension and so I have `*Repository` classes where I can do simple queries just like:

```php
   public function getRecordsByCondition($config = [],$recordPages = null) {

        $recordQuery = $this->createQuery();

        $constraints = [];
        if ($config['field1']) {
            $constraints[] = $recordQuery->equals('field1',$config['field1']));
        }
        if ($config['field2']) {
            $constraints[] = $recordQuery->equals('field2',$config['field2']));
        }
        if ($config['field3']) {
            $constraints[] = $recordQuery->equals('field3',$config['field3']));
        }
        if (count($constraints)) {
            if ($recordPages) {
                $constraints[] = $recordQuery->in('pid',$recordPages);
                $recordQuery->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
            }
            $recordQuery->matching($recordQuery->logicalAnd($constraints));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return $recordQuery->execute();
   }
```

this will respect `enableFields` and other usual conditions.

on the other hand there is the option to do it in this way:

```php
   public function getrecords2($config,$recordPages) {
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
                        ->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_myext_domain_model_records');

        $rawquery = $queryBuilder
                ->select('*')
                ->from('tx_myext_domain_model_records')
                ->where(
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('field1',$config['field1']),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('field2',$config['field2']),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('field3',$config['field3']),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->in('pid', $recordPages),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('deleted',0),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('hidden',0)
                     // starttime, endtime, language, workspace, ....
                );
        return $rawquery->execute()->fetchAll();
    }
```

where I need to care about `enablefields` by myself but have more options to specify the query.

On the first view you can see that there are other methods (`eq` vs. `equals`) and these kind of doing queries have no relation. But both work on the same table.

Now I'm at a point where I need to change all my work from first to second variant as I need a query with a `join` to another table which can't be done with first variant (as far as I know).
Have I missed something or does the first variant needs some enhancements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not sure exactly the difference but let me try to express things in brief as per my knowledge :D

The main difference between both queries is `Individual database queries` (Typically I call it Extbase query, I'm not sure I am right or not!) and another is `Doctrine DBAL Queries`

##### 1. Individual database queries

Here, as per the modern approach extension use Domain modeling. So, TYPO3 already enables a secure connection for `model` (Typically database table) and you can use relational table connection with Extbase function (Select, operational, join etc..) provided by TYPO3 core.

For more: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

##### 2. Doctrine DBAL

Here, you enable connection manually for the database table using `ConnectionPool` class. Also, you have more feasibility to establish a relation (or Join you can say!) according to your need.

For more: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/Index.html

However, you can use `restriction` for taking care if `hidden` `delete` etc.

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
                        ->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_myext_domain_model_records');

$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll()->add(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DeletedRestriction::class));
$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->add(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(HiddenRestriction::class));
$rawquery = $queryBuilder
                ->select('*')
                ->from('tx_myext_domain_model_records')
                ->where(
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('field1',$config['field1']),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('field2',$config['field2']),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('field3',$config['field3']),
                     $queryBuilder->expr()->in('pid', $recordPages)
                     // starttime, endtime, language, workspace, ....
                );
```

See: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/RestrictionBuilder/Index.html

I know this is not a sufficient and 100% correct answer. Everyone can welcome to correct me :)

Comment: most helpful is the first link, which points me to the documentation of the extbase queries. And there is a documentation to the joins which are done **implicit** by referencing the fieldname of the related table like in Fluid: `field_to_relation_table.field_in_relation`. no necessarity to call any join method.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is the first method will return an object the other one an array. On an object you could more easily retrieve child related stuf. However in my experience Extbase’s Query-object methods I would only use for very simple stuf and even with extending existing models like fe_user or news I will not use it anymore to prevent weird errors like https://forge.typo3.org/issues/75399

Answer (score 0):

> where I need to care about enablefields by myself

That's not true. By default there are `Restrictions` active and you can enable or disable every `Restriction` with a short command.

I use both approaches, but I use the first one only on Extbase extensions, the second one on every other extension. (Yes, there exist extensions without Extbase)